# Possible CSS Specificity and Inheritance Bug with nested tables

Tags: css, html-table, font-size, css-specificity

Can anyone shed some light on this?

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="size20">
      <div>Div 1 is font-size: 20px</div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>Div 2 should be font-size 20px because of inheritance and specificity</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.size20 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

td {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/geoyws/pen/wGqqMB

Comment: what is the problem and what do u want?

Comment: In css the last class effect will be overlaped by previous. It correctly inherits the size20 class but when it reaches td it overlaps the sclass size20 by td class

Comment: The problem is that he doesn't understand why the code is behaving the way it does. That's the problem. And he wants to understand. That's what he wants. It seems fairly obvious from the one-liner, "Can anyone shed some light on this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inherited value is only used when the cascade doesn't resolve a value for the given element. See ["specified values" in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specified-value).

Your inner div has a font size of 10 pixels because it inherits from the inner td, which itself has a `font-size: 10px` declaration. The value that's inherited from all of the inner td's ancestors up to `.size20` is ignored since the cascade has already determined a value for that td based on that declaration. Specificity is completely irrelevant because the `.size20` selector doesn't even match the inner td in the first place. The fact that you're dealing with tables is also irrelevant.

Everything is working as designed. There is no flaw in either the specification or browsers as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

In css the last class effect will be overlaped by previous. It correctly inherits the size20 class but when it reaches td it overlaps the class size20 by td class.
If you again need size20 effect, then you need to add that class there. And that supress the effect of td, that's what happened in first div